# What is the API to set content type in JWT token?

Tags: java, jwt

What is the API to set content type in JWT token? I want to generate nested JWT where first sign and encrypt it.

Library: Jose 0.4.1

Comment: @Hans Z: Yes I'm using jose4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way.

The method setHeader of abstract JsonWebStructure class can be used to set content type.

JsonWebSignature and JsonWebEncryption extends JsonWebStructure class, so we can use it as below.

```
JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
jws.setHeader("cty", "jwt");
```

Comment: As of v 0.4.2 there is also a `setContentTypeHeaderValue(String cty)` convenience method that does the same thing.